# How can I use UIScrollView for overlapped images iphone

Tags: iphone, image, uiscrollview, overlapping

Hi, I have a big image and small image over it at a specific location... 
I added them all under ScrollView, but it didn't work properly? 
I want to zoom in, all together each in its place

Here is my code:

```
    myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
    myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 3.0;
    myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    myScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    myScrollView.delegate = self;

    [myScrollView addSubview:imageView];
```

thanks

---

Hi, mackworth; I did it, but if I didn't maximize the image, I can't move the scroll view anywhere, but if I zoomed it, I can see the rest.. I don't know why I tried changing it, but it work. Can you please look at the following code?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ucd.png"];
    //creating a view for UCD image
    ucdView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    //setting the frame for the ucdView as the same size of ucd image
    [ucdView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];


    //for the red pin to display in specific loc
    UIImageView *Health = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"redPin.png"]];
    [Health setCenter:CGPointMake(310,135)];
    //adding helathView to ucdview
    [ucdView addSubview:Health];
    //everything for scroll view
    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, ucdView.frame.size.width, ucdView.frame.size.height)];
    [scrollView setMinimumZoomScale:1.0];
    [scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:3.0];
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [scrollView setDelegate:self];
    [scrollView addSubview:ucdView];//adding ucd view to scroll view
    [self.view addSubview:scrollView]; // adding scrollview to self.view main view
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {//apply zooming for scrollview
    return scrollView;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you implement:

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return self.imageView;
}
```

Also, you know that by setting the scrollView's contentSize to your imageSize, it can't grow any bigger than that, right?   It'll zoom in place, cropping the outer pixels accordingly.  As an aside, if that is your plan, why not just set it directly?

```
myScrollView.contentSize = imageView.frame.size;
```

=====Further answer, responding to additional source

Well, the main thing I notice is that you need to return the imageView ucdView in viewForZoomingInScrollView, not the scrollView. It looks like you already created ucdView as a property (so that it lives as long as your view does), but just in case...

1) In your .h file:

```
UIImageView * ucdView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView * ucdView;
```

2) In your .m file;

```
@synthesize ucdView;
```

3) change your line:

```
ucdView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

to just

```
 self.ucdView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
```

4) change the line

```
 return scrollView
```

to:

```
 return self.ucdView;
```

5) Add the following to your dealloc routine:

```
self.ucdView = nil;
```

Also, did you add `<UIScrollViewDelegate`> protocol to your ViewController definition (in .h file)?

Finally, you have a leak of scrollview and Health;  add [scrollView release]; and [Health release] at end of viewDidLoad

Comment: HI mackworth can u please check the answer I posted above,,,

Comment: See edited version of my answer.  Also, I'm afraid I can't quite parse "I did it, but if I didn't maximize the image, I can't move the scroll view anywhere, but if I zoomed it, I can see the rest.. I don't know why I tried changing it, but it work". Maybe take another shot?

Comment: Hi Mack, thanks a million for your answer,,, I fixed the code and yours helped me a lot....

Comment: glad to hear it.  hope it goes well from here!